# Can't modify print in scalar assignment error

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and experiencing a problem with my script. I hope somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

My browser gives me the following error output:

```
Can't modify print in scalar assignment at test.cgi line 12, near """;"
Execution of test.cgi aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

use strict;
use diagnostics;

my $radius = 5;
my $diameter = $radius * 2;

print = "The diameter is "  . $diameter . "";
```

Comment: Ok I did, but then I get a 500 internal server error

Comment: which way you are running the perl script

Comment: Check the server logs when you get an internal server error.

Comment: `print = ...` should be `print ...`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a cgi script meant to return output to a web browser, you're missing (print header() and html):

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;  # or qw/:all/
print header();  #print out html header
print "<html><body>The diameter is "  . $diameter . "</body></html>"
```

For more information on header() see https://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: Hey thank you very much! I have changed it but now I get an error at the following line: print header();

The error I get is:
Undefined subroutine &main::header called at test.cgi line 12. What could this be?

Comment: I found the solution. I added the following line: use CGI qw/:all/;

Comment: I added that to my post..Glad to see it worked for you.